# select binary(16) in jooq, but show hex string

Tags: java, mariadb, jooq

In the table is a pk with uuid's stored as binary(16).

I'm able to retrieve the hexadecimal using plain sql:

> select hex(UUID) as uuid from tbl ;

But the jooq equivalent does not know a hex function.

```
Result<Record1<byte[]>> result = ctx
                        .select(tbl.UUID)
                        .from(tbl)
                        .fetch();
```

Casting to String gives the id of the java object.

Any idea's?

```
Result<Record1<byte[]>> result = ctx
                        .select(tbl.UUID.cast(String.class))
                        .from(tbl)
                        .fetch();
```

Same problem using ip's (ipv4, ipv6):

> select inet_ntoa(conv(hex(IP), 16, 10)) as ip from tbl ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ doesn't support all vendor-specific functions out of the box. Whenever you are missing such a function, you can create it yourself using [plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/):

```
public class DSLExtensions {
    public static Field<String> hex(Field<byte[]> field) {
        return DSL.field("hex({0})", String.class, field);
    }
}
```

This obviously holds true for your other functions, too, such as `inet_ntoa()` and `conv()`

Answer (score 0):

@Lukas Eder, you can simplify that even more.

```
public static Field<String> hex(Field<byte[]> field) {
    return DSL.function("hex", String.class, field);
}
```